# No display after switching to Windows Basic (non-aero) theme

Tags: windows-7, display, aero

While trying to disable Aero in Windows 7, I went to *Personalize* and then changed the theme to the "Basic" theme in Windows 7. Now the problem is that I cannot see the desktop.

Windows starts normally; the animated Windows logo appears then I see a blank screen, although the monitor is on (and not in standby).

How can I reveret back to the other theme?

Comment: Does it display anything in Safe Mode or Low-Resolution Video Mode?

Comment: Yes it show display in safe mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On power up, start tapping F8, this will get you the Windows Advanced Boot Options screen, highlight "repair your computer" and hit enter key.

[image]

.

Once Windows Recovery Environment loads, select "repair your computer"

[image]

.

then the tools page will load, choose System Restore. pick a date before you changed the Aero setting.

[image]

Comment: +1 for detailed answer. But I dont have any restore point

Comment: Try a startup repair.